# No value given for one or more required parameters dr=ExecuteReader()

Tags: c#, oledbconnection, executereader

```
private void PopuniListu(){
    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();

    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Imeiprezimeautora FROM Tabela1";

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(dr.GetValue(0));
    }

    dr.Close();
    conn.Close();
 }
```

Here is error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.
>
> dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

Comment: There is no field named `Imeiprezimeautora` in table `Tabela1`

Comment: The field Imeiprezimeautora is 100% in table Tabela1...

Answer (score 1):

When using an `OleDb` provider (with MS-Access in particular, but I can't exclude the same for other providers) the parsing engine looks if every part of the column list in the `SELECT` clause is present in the table queried. If, for any reason (usually a typo in the column name), the engine cannot find the corresponding column it treats the name as a parameter and expects that a parameter is supplied in the `OleDbCommand.Parameters` collection.
If no parameters is present then the above error is thrown.

Another possibility is the fact that you don't initialize the `cmd` variable in the code above.
This implies that you are using a global variable for the `OleDbCommand`.
A variable that may have been used for another query and its parameter collection is not empty.

Try to add this line before executing the query

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Imeiprezimeautora FROM Tabela1";
```

However, if this is the problem, then I really suggest you to rethink this approach and avoid global variables for this kind of work.
There is no measurable performace penalty in defining and initializing an OleDbCommand locally